# Site randomly shows only text, no html

Tags: php, html, text, joomla, joomla-extensions

I hope someone can help. 
My website, roughly two months ago, after upgrading php and joonla versions, started to at various occassions display only html code, not the site itself. Here is the site url https://www.bayoubuzz.com
I have checked with the host on numerous occasions, thinking it is a apache issue or php issue and they say it is not. They say there are no errors in the error log that reflect anything related. I have checked log myself at times after it happens and there are no errors that i have seen although shortly after today's episode, I did get this error:
[Thu Mar 07 15:12:51.580826 2019] [:error] [pid 27484] [client 66.249.69.163:55866] script not found or unable to stat: /home/bayoubuz/public_html/advertising/index.php
[Thu Mar 07 15:12:51.580679 2019] [:error] [pid 27484] [client 66.249.69.163:55866] script not found or unable to stat: /home/bayoubuz/public_html/advertising/index.php

It would appear to me that googlebot could not find a folder or menu item called advertising and don't know if this is related at all. There is no menu item called advertising although a prior version of the site might have had one. The only file in that folder in file manager is the htaccess.

When it does occur and it usually seems to happen when i have done something in the joomla admin but not necessarily, I go to gtmetrix and webpagetest to check out to see the waterfall.
Here are some failed tests that occurred recently:
https://gtmetrix.com/?job_error=86FIicgT

http://webpagetest.org/result/190214_BY_93aa6805b4b06c39472eb6b2c474090e/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1

https://gtmetrix.com/?job_error=UTpM73kQ

The host sent me this link and said it appeared to be a similar problem.

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-issue-the-url-did-not-appear-to-be-an-html-page/2955

Perhaps it is a similar problem, however, I am NOT  a coder and don't know exactly what I would need to do to correct and not convinced it is not host-related.
Last, I have noticed that on the front page of the site, there is some type of error that I started to see roughly around the same time period of the inception of the problem...
You are here:    Home  Oops--Page not here

Sorry for my ignorance here but any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.
s.

Comment: This is related to some settings about PHP in your Host. See this: https://www.itoctopus.com/php-code-is-showing-on-joomla-website

Comment: Maybe some your scripts have short tags but your host doesn't have short tags enabled?

Comment: This happens when I open your linked page too. `content-type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8` is one of the response headers, therefore it makes sense that the browser just shows the text, I'd suggest you try and find why this header is sent

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with you joomla installation, the html header shows:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8" />
```

So the browser thinks it's and RSS feed in XML, and shows it as XML. It should be

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

check your joomla installation and/or reinstall it.